# Class with a db query, extending, functions and views. Am I doing it right way?

Tags: php, class

I have just a little progress in practicing. Most of my code works but I am not sure if I do things the right way?

Please, can you tell me if I do mistakes and correct me.

**First, I create autoload functions:**

```
function autoload_models($model) {
    if (file_exists(MODELS_PATH . $model . '.php')) {
        require_once MODELS_PATH . $model . '.php';
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload_models');


function autoload_controllers($controller) {
    if (file_exists(CONTROLLERS_PATH . $controller . '.php')) {
        require_once CONTROLLERS_PATH . $controller . '.php';
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload_controllers');
```

**I have a class like this:**

```
class Category {

    public $db;
    public $rows;
    public $id;

    public function build_category() {

        global $db;
        global $rows;

        $db = new Database();
        $db->query("SELECT * from categories");
        $rows = $db->resultset();
    }

    public function category_items() {

        global $db;
        global $rows;
        global $id;

        $db = new Database();
        $db->query("SELECT * from posts WHERE category_id = '$id'");
        $rows = $db->resultset();
    }

}
```

**I extend with another class** *(still have some issues here. **Nothing** prints)*:

```
class Category_Items extends Category {

    public $db;
    public $rows;
    public $id;

    public function display_category_items() {

        // Call the parent class function
        parent::category_items();

        global $rows;
        global $id;


        // Check if the page parameter is integer
        if (ctype_digit($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
        } else {
            print "Illegal category page parameter";
        }


        foreach ($rows as $row) {

            print "test";
            print $row['post_title']; // This does not work yet. Nothing prints
        }
    }

}
```

**Class for building a menu with categories** *(Everything works here)*:

```
class Categories_Menu extends Category {

    public $db;
    public $rows;

    public function build_category_menu() {

        parent::build_category();

        global $rows;

        foreach ($rows as $row) {

            require VIEWS_PATH . 'categories/categories_menu.php';
        }
    }

}
```

And finally instances:

```
$category_menu = new Categories_Menu();
$category_menu->build_category_menu();

$category_items = new Category_Items();
$category_items->display_category_items();
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Do you know what an `ORM` is?

Comment: Assuming you are using PHP5 you should use the magic `__construct()` function in your classes and not a class method/function. Also, rather than refer to the object's properties with `global $propertyName` use `$this->propertyName`

Comment: Hi, Peter! I have been told that constructors are not required and I can avoid them. Do I always have to make constructors? Thank you!

Comment: No, if you don't need them. Peter maybe has mistaken, because you have used `parent::`, which is commonly used when using constructors in inherited classes

Comment: I am really confused, guys! :) Thank you! I suppose I will get things with time and practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do the global variables come from?

Anyway, you should get rid of them.

I guess your rows var does not get changed, after any interaction. Using globals also will not be relevant in extending classes.

Your public properties and globals mentioned, does no interact each other. Thus, the object members seems to be totally useless.

What I would suggest in simple schems would be

```
class Model {

    protected $_db;

    public function __construct(Database $db) {
        $this->_db = $db;
    }
}


class Category extends Model {

    public $_rows;
    public $_id;

    public function build_category() {
        $this->_db->query("SELECT * from categories");
        $this->_rows = $this->_db->resultset();
    }

    public function category_items() {
        $this->_db->query("SELECT * from posts WHERE category_id = '{$this->_id}'");
        $this->_rows = $this->_db->resultset(); // here you will overwrite $_rows ?
    }


class Categories_Menu extends Category {

    public $_rows;

    public function build_category_menu() {
        $this->build_category();
        foreach ($this->_rows as $row) {
            require VIEWS_PATH . 'categories/categories_menu.php';
        }
    }
} 


class Category_Items extends Category {

    public $_rows;
    public $_id;

    public function display_category_items() {

        if (ctype_digit($_GET['id'])) { // just intval it, or use is_int?
            $this->_id = $_GET['id'];
        } else {
            print "Illegal category page parameter";
        }

        // You assign value to $_id, then call the function that requires it

        $this->category_items();

        foreach ($this->_rows as $row) {

            print "test";
            print $row['post_title'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx you, Royal Bg! This is kind of different. The child class is also a parent of another child class. And the first master class in only this - one connection to the database? Is this an instance of the Database class: __construct(Database $db)? I will try it now this way and I will do more classes according this schema.

Comment: Your very very master class (Model) which should be extended by each Model (class, which uses database) recieves as parameter an already instantiated Database object (that's the only typehinting that PHP supports). Basically it means somewhere in your application your code will render to `$db = new Database(); $SomeModel = new NameOfTheModel($db)`

Comment: I have an error and I do not know how to fix it as I do not understand the problem :( 
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Model::__construct() must be an instance of Database, none given, called in E:\xampp\htdocs\projects\newscms\category.php on line 8 and defined in E:\xampp\htdocs\projects\newscms\application\models\Model.php on line 7

Comment: I did some random changes in Model and it works now: class Model {

    protected $_db;

    public function __construct() {
        
        $this->_db = new Database;

    }

}